# ionic code push update failure: Could not get the package start page at preInstallFailure

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, code-push

I encountered the following error after I update from the app on client. The app on client did retrieve the update release. But then the error occured.

```
[app-scripts] [15:01:09]  console.error: [CodePush] An error has occured while installing the package. Could not get the package start
[app-scripts]             page. StackTrace: Error: An error has occured while installing the package. Could not get the package start
[app-scripts]             page at preInstallFailure
[app-scripts]             (http://192.168.2.3:8100/plugins/cordova-plugin-code-push/bin/www/localPackage.js:246:41) at
[app-scripts]             Object.callbackFromNative (http://192.168.2.3:8100/cordova.js:293:52) at processMessage
[app-scripts]             (http://192.168.2.3:8100/cordova.js:1114:17) at processMessages (http://192.168.2.3:8100/cordova.js:1137:9)
[app-scripts]             at http://192.168.2.3:8100/build/vendor.js:130322:26 at t.invoke
[app-scripts]             (http://192.168.2.3:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14976) at r.run
[app-scripts]             (http://192.168.2.3:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10143) at http://192.168.2.3:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20242
[app-scripts]             at t.invokeTask (http://192.168.2.3:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15660) at r.runTask
[app-scripts]             (http://192.168.2.3:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10834)
```

Here is my config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="cn.bookheart.app" version="0.0.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    ...
    <content original-src="index.html" src="http://192.168.2.3:8100" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    ...
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
        <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
        ...
    </platform>
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "example",
    "version": "0.0.2",
    "homepage": "http://example.com/",
    ...
```

I tried to reinstall platform android and then update release, but it was the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you builded Ionic before making release with `ionic build cordova android`.

As `release-cordova` command builds only cordova project(not Ionic).